# Linux Bootstrap consuming Memory

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

My server gets crash/down after 2 hrs of restarting. When I viewed the process it showed me

```
 PID   USER     PR  NI    VIRT     RES    SHR   S   %CPU    %MEM    TIME+     COMMAND
 13209  root    25   0    3681m    2.3g   9.9m  S    98.0    87.3   16:11.09    java
```

The PID referred to  13209 "Bootstrap".  the %CPU keeps moving 100%, 113% and server is down. After tomcat restart, it is ok till 2 hrs but again same problem arises. What to do with "Bootstrap" process so that it doesn't consume so much of memory!

```
       Any Solution??
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably a problem with your web application?

Comment: @LtWorf  but my web application was working nicely without server down....  this problem appeared from yesterday only..   Also what might have affected this..   any examples?

Comment: while (True) {}; is a good enough example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command while the server is unusually busy:

```
kill -3 13209
```

Replacing 13209 with the current PID of the java process.  This will output a thread dump to the log file (catalina.out by default).  Take a look a what the threads are doing, and that will give you a better idea about which part of the application is pegging the CPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! you saved my life.. needed this solution!!